# Retrieving & storing variables in an object reference loop

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to set the value of a field of a related object, having retrieved the record using an SOQL query.

```
trigger WE_IMProjCmpltnUp on MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c (before insert, before update) {

List<WEID__c> weids = WEID__c.getall().values();
Set<Id> validRecordTypeIds = new Set<Id>();

//add Opportunity Record Type Ids from Custom Setting to list of valid Ids      
for(WEID__c weid : weids) {
    try{
        validRecordTypeIds.add(weid.WEProjectId__c);
    }catch (System.StringException e) {
        System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,'Invalid Record Type Id ' + weid.WEProjectId__c);
    }
}

Set<Id> projects = new Set<Id>();
Map<Id,Date> deadlineDates = new Map<Id,Date>();
List<Opportunity> updOpps = new List<Opportunity>();

If(Trigger.isInsert){
    for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c p : Trigger.new){
        if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(p.RecordTypeId) && p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c != null)
        {
            projects.add(p.Id);
            deadlineDates.put(p.Id, p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c);
        }
    }
}

If(Trigger.isUpdate){
            for(MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c p : Trigger.new){
                if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(p.RecordTypeId) && p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c != null)
                {
                    MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Project__c oldP = Trigger.oldMap.get(p.Id);

                    if(oldP.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c != p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c){
                        projects.add(p.Id);
                        deadlineDates.put(p.Id, p.MPM4_BASE__Deadline__c);
                    }
                }
            }
}

if(projects.size() > 0){

    for(ProjectxOpp__c junc : [SELECT Project__c, Opportunity__r.Implementation_Revenue__c FROM ProjectxOpp__c
                                WHERE Project__c In :projects])
    {
        Opportunity o = junc.Opportunity__r;
        o.Implementation_Revenue__c = deadlineDates.get(junc.Project__c);
        updOpps.add(o);
    }
    update updOpps;
}
```

}

The above works fine but when I change `o.Implementation_Revenue__c = deadlineDates.get(junc.Project__c);` to:

```
Date newCompDate =  deadlineDates.get(junc.Project__c);
            if(newCompDate > o.Implementation_Revenue__c){
                o.Implementation_Revenue__c = newCompDate;
            }
```

And check that the Opportunity field `Implementation_Revenue__c` has been updated with the date in the deadlineDates map, my system assert tells me that the field's value is null.

Also, when I add debug lines, for example

```
Opportunity o = junc.Opportunity__r;
system.debug('junc Project__c >>>>> ' + junc.Project__c);
```

the debug statements don't appear in my log.

I don't understand why I'm not able to fetch the values from the map, as usual, in this loop?

Comment: Can you share the entirety of your trigger please?

Comment: @BrianMansfield I've updated the post.

Comment: Alex, when you say the debug statements aren't appearing in your log, do you mean the value is null, or you can't find the statement at all?

Comment: @BrianMansfield I can't find them at all, I'm just using the standard developer console and filtering to debug only. Then filtering for >>>.

Comment: You might have got some exception which has skipped debug statement from getting printed. I doubt on **newCompDate > o.Implementation_Revenue__c **this statement.

Comment: @San thanks, I guess it's hard to debug that one ;) should the exception be in my log though or would I have to check each line?

Comment: It should be in your logs. Try to print value of o.Implementation_Revenue__c and see what value it is printing before if block if(newCompDate > o.Implementation_Revenue__c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the issue, was that I had not set a date for the Opportunity `Implementation_Revenue__c` in my Test Class.

So the line `if(newCompDate > o.Implementation_Revenue__c){` was evaluating to false because

> When checking whether x > y, if x or y equal null and are Integers, Doubles, Dates, or Datetimes, the expression is false.

[Understanding Expression Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm)